# Method call: Method toObject(java.util.LinkedHashMap) cannot be found on org.springframework.integration.x.gemfire.JsonStringToObjectTransformer

Tags: spring-xd, gemfire

I am facing the following issue in Spring XD and gemfire

```
nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method toObject(java.util.LinkedHashMap) cannot be found on org.springframework.integration.x.gemfire.JsonStringToObjectTransformer type.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Following is how we can replicate this issue:

```
stream create json_test --definition "trigger --fixedDelay=1 | 
transform --expression='''{node1 : {node2 : {data1:hello, data2: world}}}''' | 
splitter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.node1.node2') | 
log" --deploy`
```

What we are expecting `{data1:hello, data2:world}` but we are getting `{data1=hello, data2=world}` which is causing the issue.

What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the full stack trace, as well as your stream definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gemfire-json-server` sink can only handle incoming String JSON payloads; it looks like you are supplying a `LinkedHashMap` somehow.

It probably means you have run it through some JSON to object transformation or conversion.

**EDIT**

The splitter produces a `LinkedHashMap` - specify an `outputType` to convert it to JSON...

```
xd:>stream create json_test --definition "trigger --fixedDelay=1 | 
transform --expression='''{node1 : {node2 : {data1:hello, data2: world}}}''' | 
splitter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.node1.node2') --outputType=application/json |
log" --deploy
```

Result...

```
2017-06-14T09:52:10-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-2 sink.json_test - {"data1":"hello","data2":"world"}
2017-06-14T09:52:11-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-2 sink.json_test - {"data1":"hello","data2":"world"}
2017-06-14T09:52:12-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO task-scheduler-2 sink.json_test - {"data1":"hello","data2":"world"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please see the example stream i have added in the question. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: See my edit - you need to convert the `#jsonPath` output back to JSON.